# Regex to remove commas before a number in python

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I'm working with a file using commas as a delimiter. However, it has a field, address in it where the address is of form x,y,z which causes a problem as each part of the address gets a new column entry. The address is immediately followed by member_no a 1 digit number like 2 etc.
Col1 (Address), Col2(1 Digit number)

```
text = '52A, XYZ Street, ABC District, 2'
```

I basically want to remove all commas before that number from the address field.

The output should be like

```
52A XYZ Street ABC District, 2'
```

I tried

```
re.sub(r',', ' ', text)
```

but it's replacing all instances of commas.

Comment: Not 100% sure regex is the way to go, unless you can be sure that no street names start with a number (e.g. 5th Avenue).

Comment: All parts of the address are attached to an alphabet like 52A. There are no standalone numbers in the address space.

Comment: Do you want to say you only want to remove commas before the first "standalone" number? Like `re.sub(r'^(.*?)(,\s*\d+\b)', lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1).replace(',', ''), x.group(2)), s)`?

Comment: Yes exactly @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the response but unfortunately it's not working in my case. I'm still getting the commas before the standalone number.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the `,` before that first comma. Is it always there, or can it be missing? Also, see https://ideone.com/4ai0dI

Comment: Sometimes it can be missing

Comment: That sounds like a riddle. Try https://ideone.com/4ai0dI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a zero-width negative lookahead to make sure the to be replaced substrings (commas here) are not followed by `{space(s)}{digit}` at the end:

```
,(?!\s+\d$)
```

**Example:**

```
In [227]: text = '52A, XYZ Street, ABC District, 2'

In [228]: re.sub(',(?!\s+\d$)', '', text)
Out[228]: '52A XYZ Street ABC District, 2'
```

---

**Edit:**

If you have more commas after the `,{space(s)}{digit}` substring, and want to keep them all, leverage a negative lookbehind to make sure the commas are not preceded by `{space}{digit<or>[A-Z]}`:

```
(?<!\s[\dA-Z]),(?!\s+\d,?)
```

**Example:**

```
In [229]: text = '52A, XYZ Street, ABC District, 2, M, Brown'

In [230]: re.sub('(?<!\s[\dA-Z]),(?!\s+\d,?)', '', text)
Out[230]: '52A XYZ Street ABC District, 2, M, Brown'

In [231]: text = '52A, XYZ Street, ABC District, 2'

In [232]: re.sub('(?<!\s[\dA-Z]),(?!\s+\d,?)', '', text)
Out[232]: '52A XYZ Street ABC District, 2'
```

Comment: What if I have something else after the digit. Like, say
text = '52A, XYZ Street, ABC District, 2, M, Brown' ?? Appreciate your answer.

Comment: @RohitGirdhar Whats your desired output from that?

Comment: It should be of the form: 52A XYZ Street ABC District, 2, M, Brown with commas staying intact after that single digit numbers but getting removed before the number

Comment: Accepted your Answer. WiktorStribiżew also had a nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

If at the end is just a single digit you could use this. Can adapt if after the last comma are multiple digits(number 3 should be incremented).

```
text = '52A, XYZ Street, ABC District, 2'
text = text[:-3].replace(",", "") + text[-3:]
print(text)
```

The output is

```
52A XYZ Street ABC District, 2
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a regular expression. You can just look for the last occurence of `,` and use that, as in:

```
text[:text.rfind(',')].replace(',', '') + text[text.rfind(','):]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is especially for currencies. It won't remove comma in dates and other places.

```
mystring="he has 1,00000,00 ruppees and lost 50,00,00,000,00,000,00 june 20, 1970 and 30/23/34 1, 2, 3"

print(re.sub(r'(?:(\d+?)),(\d+?)',r'\1\2',mystring))
```